# Get Apple clang version and corresponding upstream LLVM version

Tags: macos, c++11, clang, c++14

I want to understand which version of clang Apple installed in my macbook, to see with c++11 and/or c++14 features are available.
I typed this command:

```
clang --version

//----response
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)     
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0    
Thread model: posix
```

But I am not able to understand what `(clang-700.1.76)` mean.
How can I convert this code to a clang version?

This is the site where you could check c++ features available in clang version http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: Apparently, it used to report the upstream LLVM version it was based on: [Xcode clang versions](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292), but as you found it no longer does. I'd guess either 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: Retitled *"Get Apple clang version and corresponding upstream LLVM version"* to summarize things

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The (Apple) version number of the compiler is mostly useless, since you also need to consider whether your code is compiled with `libstdc++` or with `libc++` (or any other standard library) - and which version of those.

If you want to test for language or library features, it is better to check other defined values, e.g., `__cplusplus`, `__cpp_constexpr`, `__cpp_variadic_templates`, etc. It is not perfect, but it seems to work better (if you want portability) in my experience and the support from all major compiler is improving.

Each C++ standard version defines a value for `__cplusplus`, some compilers use intermediate values to say "we already started on C++14, but we are not there yet". Use `>=` to test when needed.

The other feature test macros are similar, you can find the current version at [N4440](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4440.html). Not all compilers implement N4440, though.

Comment: "The version number of the compiler is mostly useless" What? I want to know if a bug I've seen in their tracker has been fixed. if I know it's a clang bug (related to constexpr or whatever else), how is it **mostly useless**? That's a big, unsupported claim

Comment: @Ven This is meant **in the context of this question**, not universally. The version number is mostly useless for feature detection when the standard library is involved as the compiler version number does not (and can not) include which version of `libstdc++` is used. Also, since Apple is using a different version schema than Clang, you can not simply match Apple's version number against Clang's bug database.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't answer the specific question of determining the `clang` version.

Comment: @ray OP also writes: "I want to understand which version of clang Apple installed in my macbook, **to see with c++11 and/or c++14 features are available**". This, to me, seemed like the question he wants an answer to, not just the title of his post. Also, looking at https://trac.macports.org/wiki/XcodeVersionInfo from Mike's answer, it is clear that Apple doesn't really document what their version of Clang is based on compared to the official Clang version. I'm still waiting for a better answer how to solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 34):

Wikipedia's Xcode page has [a map of Apple to LLVM versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_12.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)). The LLVM column has the open-source LLVM/Clang version. From this you can look up a language feature in cppreference's [chart of compiler support for language features](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Answer (score 23):

Here is the best listing I've found that correlates Apple's clang versions with the LLVM versions:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/XcodeVersionInfo

Previous versions used to say what LLVM version they corresponded to, but starting with 7.0, Apple decided to no longer do that.  They even define the `__clang_version__` and related preprocessor macros to indicate the Apple version number, not the LLVM version.  So they're useless for this as well.

Unfortunately, it looks like the only way to see if you have a feature is to try it and check if it works.  e.g. 7.0.2 still doesn't have OpenMP enabled by default (although it's [enable-able](http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html)), so I guess it's still 3.6, not 3.7 yet.

Comment: That page hasn’t listed corresponding LLVM versions since Xcode 7 (2015), unlike https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions

Answer (score 9):

As hinted by [`pkolbus`](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292#gistcomment-1950357), you can look at the `/src/CMakeLists.txt` to guess the corresponding Clang version. For example, Apple Clang [800.0.38](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.38/src/CMakeLists.txt.auto.html) and [800.0.42.1](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.42.1/src/CMakeLists.txt.auto.html) both seem to based on Clang 3.9.0 according to

```
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR 3)
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_MINOR)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_MINOR 9)
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_PATCH)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_PATCH 0)
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED LLVM_VERSION_SUFFIX)
  set(LLVM_VERSION_SUFFIX svn)
endif()
```

Comment: which `/src/CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @Walter the one from Clang. I have linked to two examples in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions

---

```
Xcode    cctools[93]      ld64[94]      LLVM[85]      Clang version string[95] 
8.3.3    898              278.4         3.9.0svn[85]  8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)[80]
9.0      900              302.3         4.0.0?[86]    9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)[80]
9.1      900              302.3.1       4.0.0?[87]    9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)[80]
9.2      900              305           4.0.0?[88]    9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)[80]
9.3      906              351.8         5.0.2?[89]    9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)[80]
9.3.1    906              351.8         5.0.2?[89]    9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)[80]
9.4      906              351.8         5.0.2?[90]    9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)[80]
9.4.1    906              351.8         5.0.2?[90]    9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)[80]
10.0     921.0.1          409.12        6.0.1?[91]    10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)[80]
10.1     921.0.1          409.12        6.0.1?[92]    10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)[80]
```

For example, Apple CLang 10.x is LLVM 6.0.1 based.

Answer (score 5):

First, I want to say that Daniel Frey's answer is absolutely correct; you really should be using `__has_feature`, `__has_extension`, *etc*. when possible.  The [Clang Language Extensions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) page documents the different things you can check for, and that should be your go-to solution.

That said, sometimes you really do need to check the version.  For example, sometimes it is necessary to work around compiler bugs which have been fixed in newer versions, or which only appear in newer versions.  Sometimes new functionality is added; for example, prior to clang 9 [`__builtin_constant_p` didn't work correctly with the `diagnose_if` attribute](https://godbolt.org/z/Wh57dj).  Sometimes a feature is added but there is no corresponding check.

I really wish clang would just expose the upstream version numbers as preprocessor macros so we could reliably handle cases like that, but they don't.  You could manually create a map of Apple version numbers to upstream, which is what several other answers have proposed, but that has some pretty obvious drawbacks.  For me, the fatal flaw is that it doesn't really work for compilers other than Apple clang; there are a lot of compilers based on clang these days (IBM XL C/C++, some newer PGI/NVIDIA compilers, next-gen Intel C/C++, etc.).

My work-around is to use feature detection macros to estimate a version number.  For example, `-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion` was added in clang 11, so if `__has_warning("-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion")` is true we can assume the upstream clang version is >= 11.  Similarly, clang 10 added `-Wmisleading-indentation`, clang 9 started definining the `__FILE_NAME__` preprocessor macro, etc.

I've created [a small header](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/master/simde/simde-detect-clang.h) which contains the necessary logic.  It's public domain (CC0), and even though it is part of one of my projects ([SIMDe](https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde)) it doesn't depend on anything else from any other files, so you're free to steal it for your own projects without copying all of SIMDe.

Obviously the file needs a new test for each version of clang, so it does require occasional updates if you need to be able to check for newer compilers, so I'd suggest grabbing the latest version from the SIMDe git repository (I'm not likely to keep this answer up to date), but here is what the checks look like right now:

```c
#if defined(__clang__) && !defined(SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION)
#  if __has_warning("-Wformat-insufficient-args")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 120000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 110000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wmisleading-indentation")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 100000
#  elif defined(__FILE_NAME__)
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 90000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wextra-semi-stmt") || __has_builtin(__builtin_rotateleft32)
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 80000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wc++98-compat-extra-semi")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 70000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wpragma-pack")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 60000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wbitfield-enum-conversion")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 50000
#  elif __has_attribute(diagnose_if)
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 40000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wcomma")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 39000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wdouble-promotion")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 38000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wshift-negative-value")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 37000
#  elif __has_warning("-Wambiguous-ellipsis")
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 36000
#  else
#    define SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION 1
#  endif
#endif /* defined(__clang__) && !defined(SIMDE_DETECT_CLANG_VERSION) */
```

I think the biggest problem with this method is actually shared with all other attempts to detect the upstream clang version that I'm aware of: there isn't necessarily a clang release that corresponds to the code in question.  As far as I can tell, most compilers based on clang aren't actually based on releases, but rather some random commit (probably whatever is the latest commit for the branch they want to base their work on).  That means that, for example, if an issue is was fixed late in the clang $N development cycle, Apple's fork may generally be the same as clang $N but not contain the bug fix.  Conversely, maybe Apple will back-port a fix from clang $N+1 and a bug present in clang $N will be fixed in Apple's version.

Answer (score 2):

One can try to *compile* some file with *--verbose* option.

For example:
c++ --verbose -c test1.cpp

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name test1.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 253.9 -v -dwarf-column-info -coverage-file /Users/az/ctest/test1.cpp -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/az/ctest -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 130 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o test1.o -x c++ test1.cpp
clang -cc1 version 7.0.2 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
```

It does print LLVM svn version (3.7.0 in our example)

Comment: Does not work any more for current Apple clang, see https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/7734385cdd7eee4cfc6c6171725ffb1c

Answer (score 1):

If you use the strings command on the compiler you might get the LLVM version.

For example if you have the clang version that identifies itself as *Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)*, the output of strings will have this value:

```
LLVM 3.7.0svn
```

This doesn't appear to work with version *Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)*

Comment: Current Apple clang strings only contain the binary name. Or am I missing something here? https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/73dee3783694b04987290e5b120aa3e5

Comment: @SimonWarta The Xcode command line tools in /usr are actually just shortcuts to the real tools installed inside the Xcode bundle. Use `strings "$(xcrun --find clang)" | grep LLVM`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed clion, in it's **preference-toolchains**, you might see 'debugger' as **bundled LLDB 7.0.1**.

I believe this is the current Apple clang version. (eg.Apple LLVM version 10.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

As your Terminal output

```
clang --version
//----response
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)     
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0    
Thread model: posix
```

The first line "`Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)`" means:
Your `Xcode7.1` with embedded `Clang7.0.0`(The `Clang7.0.0` Identifier:`clang-700.1.76`).

From this [website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions), i know your Clang version is `7.0.0`.
If Clang version is >= `Clang5.0`, [that Clang support C++11 or C++14](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).