# libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a is not found on macOS

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, libfuzzer

When compiling with the `-fsanitize=fuzzer` flag to include libfuzzer in LLVM on macOS, I get the error:

```
libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a is not found
```

The LLVM/clang compiler I'm using  is bundled with Xcode, 14.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the version of Clang bundled with LLVM in Xcode excludes libfuzzer.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Install a version of LLVM from homebrew (`brew install llvm`)
2. Download the full bundle of LLVM from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases matching the version installed in Xcode. Extract the archive and copy all `libclang_rt.fuzzer*` files from the archive's `lib/darwin` directory into the Xcode path for the libraries -
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin`

Comment: Ré option 2: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259269/795690 helpful for working out which version of LLVM I actually have; also FWIW the path to copy to, if using only Command Line Tools is something like `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin` (depending on version). Thank you!